# TextView's scrollbar style

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The Scroll Indicator Style only has 3 settings, Default, White and Black. I want it to be Orange, how do I change the colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can't customize this without delving deep into the source code, which is not recommended - black and white it is!